# photoshop how do I use shape tool without fill

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to use the shape tool in photoshop to create a profile picture. I'm using the shape tool but it automatically fills in with a color. How can I turn off "auto fill"?

Thanks - Adolfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top left you'll see a fill thing.

[image]

After you click on it you can click on the square with a red stripe in it and then it will be without fill.